# Visual Studio How to save and load a list Box?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to save and load a few list boxes back in, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
Private Sub saveTransaction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveTransaction.Click
    alltransactions.amountList.Items.Add(amountBox.Text)
    alltransactions.dateList.Items.Add(dateBox.Text)
    alltransactions.idList.Items.Add(idBox.Text)
    alltransactions.serverList.Items.Add(serverBox.Text)

    My.Settings.AmountList.Add(amountBox.Text)
    My.Settings.DateList.Add(dateBox.Text)
    My.Settings.IDList.Add(idBox.Text)
    My.Settings.ServerList.Add(serverBox.Text)

End Sub
```

Here's the loading portion of it: (just trying to load one, but it doesn't even work)

```
Private Sub alltransactions_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    amountList.Text = My.Settings.AmountList.ToString

End Sub
```

Here's the issues i'm having. If I try to load allTransactions.vb before I add 1, I get Object rederence not set to an instance of an object. I'm assuming this is because I haven't even set one, so fair enough. But if i save it:

```
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

^ That happens when I save the first thing of code i showed, on all boxes. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Just an idea: Give a look at C# WPF Binding, maybe you will find to be easier to do these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want. But for example if you want to save the items of ListBox1 you may save it in a text document like this:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines("ListBox1_Contents.txt", ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray())
```

To load the file again in the ListBox1 you may use this code:

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("ListBox1_Contents.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a `Specialized.StringCollection` you need to check if it's been initialized before using it if in this case this is the type being used.

```
If My.Settings.AmountList Is Nothing Then
    My.Settings.AmountList = New Specialized.StringCollection
End If
```

To load ListBox items

```
My.Settings.AmountList.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
```

Or a TextBox

```
My.Settings.AmountList.Add(TextBox1.Text)
```

The above will work since we initialized the collection. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a *alternate to using My.Settings* and if not open to this go no farther.

Here is another approach. Declare a private variable that points to the path and file name to read data from for the ListBox.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ListBoxfileName As String =
        IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Names.txt")
```

Load the file via a language extension (at bottom of my reply)

```
If IO.File.Exists(ListBoxfileName) Then
    ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile(ListBoxfileName)
End If
```

Save the items on form closing

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(
    sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile(ListBoxfileName)

End Sub
```

Now you need to create ListBoxExtensions and add it to your project, add the following, build and run

```
Public Module ListBoxExtensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Save unbound items to a file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="FileName">File to save items too</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub SaveToFile(ByVal sender As ListBox.ObjectCollection, ByVal FileName As String)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName,
            (From Row In sender.Cast(Of String)() Select Row).ToArray())
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Save unbound items to a file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="FileName">File to save items too</param>
    ''' <param name="Append">Indicates whether new contents should be appended to existing file</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub SaveToFile(ByVal sender As ListBox.ObjectCollection, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Append As Boolean)
        Dim Items = (From Row In sender.Cast(Of String)() Select Row).ToList

        If Append Then
            If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
                Dim CurrentFileLines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName).ToList
                Items.AddRange(CurrentFileLines)
            End If
        End If

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, Items.ToArray)

    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub LoadFromFile(ByVal sender As ListBox.ObjectCollection, ByVal FileName As String)
        sender.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
    End Sub
End Module
```